# Strange time format output by flink

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying flatAggregate,
the whole code is bug free and as follows:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TM6n2jdZfr/

the result I get is:

8> (true,1,+1705471-09-26T16:50,+1705471-09-26T16:55,+1705471-09-26T16:54:59.999,4,1)
4> (true,3,+1705471-09-26T16:50,+1705471-09-26T16:55,+1705471-09-26T16:54:59.999,2,1)
7> (true,1,+1705471-09-26T16:50,+1705471-09-26T16:55,+1705471-09-26T16:54:59.999,3,1)
8> (true,1,+1705471-09-26T16:50,+1705471-09-26T16:55,+1705471-09-26T16:54:59.999,4,2)
4> (true,3,+1705471-09-26T16:50,+1705471-09-26T16:55,+1705471-09-26T16:54:59.999,2,2)
7> (true,1,+1705471-09-26T16:50,+1705471-09-26T16:55,+1705471-09-26T16:54:59.999,3,2)

the time format seems strange,
for example,
`+1705471-09-26T16:50`
what's this?

Where am I wrong in my code?
Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that your `WatermarkStrategy` does not define a timestamp extractor.